# Need feature like emojiesand feedback to get rendered in every bot responses

Tags: botframework, web-chat

I saw there are **emojis** attached with every message in microsoft teams.
Is it possible to implement the same scenario in webchat. if yes please help me to achieve it.
i also want a code snippet to render feedback **thumbs up** and **thumbs down** button in every bot response.
i need an explanary code snippet using javascript or jquery and a small demo(if possible).

Answer (score 1):

The WebChat is easy to extend, thus your scenario should be possible. There is an example that is close to your needs.

Have a look at the [WebChat documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), sample [`09.customization-reaction-buttons`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/09.customization-reaction-buttons). ([demo](https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/09.customization-reaction-buttons/)).

> Introduces the ability to create custom components for Web Chat that
>   are unique to your bot's needs. This tutorial demonstrates the ability
>   to add reaction emoji such as  and  to conversational activities.

Comment: webchat is having only feedback thumbs up and thumbsdown feature and webchat donot supports emojies. i tried adding the different emojies same like in micosoft teams but it cannot get handles at serverside in microsft bot framework coding.

Comment: @Bradrajkumar, WebChat supports every emoji, not just the thumbs up and down. You can easily extend the WebChat, as you can see in my example. Of course, you have to make sure that you catch it in your bot back-end, but if you use the example code, you could just listen to the `messageReaction` event.

Comment: yes it supports all the emojies but if the emojies i want to add up with feedback(same like in MS teams) at that time activity type is not taking as a messageReaction for emojies(it is taking only thumbs up and thumbs down). This is what i found/experience. please correct me if i am wrong.